# How would I adapt the file() function in Python2 to a Python3 function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, io

### Primary Issue

I am currently trying to run [this](https://github.com/MTG/DeepConvSep) particular Github Project on my Mac OS. It was most certainly coded for a system running Python 2. However, I am running Python3 and I need to make a few modifications to the program. Most of these modifications work seamlessly, except for the one below.

When I run the program with this command...

```
python3 separate_dsd.py -i ./../../Ricotti\ \&\ Alburquerque\ -\ Dont\ You\ Believe\ Me.mp3 -o ./ -m ./../../model1.pkl
```

...I get the error `NameError: name 'file' is not defined`. File has been replaced with `io.open` within Python3. However, simply replacing the function call with `io.open` is giving me an error.

The specific line is, `f=file(filename,'rb')` of the code block:

```
def load_model(filename):
    f=file(filename,'rb')
    params=pickle.load(f)
    f.close()
    return params
```

This resides in the file `/DeepConvSep/examples/dsd100/separate_dsd.py`. Now how would I go about replacing the exact behaviour of `file(filename,'rb')` with a `io.open`?

---

### Responses to Answers Below

Currently I tried to follow @abarnert's suggestions and changed my code to:

```
def load_model(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        return pickle.load(f)
```

But I still get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "separate_dsd.py", line 336, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "separate_dsd.py", line 333, in main
    train_auto(inputfile,outdir,model,0.3,30,25,32,513)
  File "separate_dsd.py", line 250, in train_auto
    params=load_model(model)
  File "separate_dsd.py", line 19, in load_model
    params=pickle.load(f)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xbb in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Have you tried running `2to3` on the code? You don't have to let it auto-fix the code for you, but reading its diffs as suggestions is very helpful. In this case, it should suggest using `open` in place of `file`, which is exactly what you need to get started.

Comment: Actually, without testing… it might *not* suggest that. Because `file` was already not-quite-deprecated-but-discouraged in favor of `open` somewhere in the 2.3-2.5 era, and the `2to3` checker assumes you're starting with idiomatic 2.6 or 2.7 code…

Comment: @abarnert Look at my edits above. Let me try and run 2to3

Comment: Can you show us the code you tried that generated that? Did you by any chance leave off the `'rb'` mode? In Python 3, that means you want to decode the file to Unicode text using your default encoding, and that's not going to work with a binary file.

Comment: @abarnert Please look at my edits, this would probably make it more clear as to what I tried.

Comment: OK, that's exactly the problem. When you changed from `file` to `open`, you took off the `b` mode. Don't do that. For more info, see my answer.

Comment: @abarnert, let me try your solution, but at the very start, I never took off the `b` mode.

Comment: OK, next problem: Did you save a pickle file with Python 2 and then try to load it back in Python 3?

Comment: Also—which 2.x version, and did your code just do `pickle.dump(s, f)`, or did it specify an explicit pickle protocol version? Also, can you verify that your Python 2.x script can actually read the file?

Comment: I never really save a pickle file or such. As specified above, this is a Github project that I have pulled onto my system. But I can answer your questions, if you could guide me as to the procedure to find out this info.

Comment: also, 

1.) Should we move this to a chat? 

2.) I have made edits to the question in order to reflect the current changes I have made to the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166643/discussion-between-abarnert-and-sharan-duggirala).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you've got at least two options:

a) Replace the call to `file()`, with `open()` which is a built-in function in Python 3

b) Learn how to use the immensely helpful `venv` (virtual python environment) and create a runtime environment for this project using an instance of a Python 2 interpreter.

If you choose the former, you must specify that you're trying to read a binary file when you call `open()`:

```
open(filename, 'rb')
```

However, given that this is probably not the only instance, in this project, of an incompatibility between your Python 3 interpreter and the source code, I would suggest creating a Python 2 environment.

Comment: I have had some bad experiences with virtual Python environments and would generally try to avoid them. Could you please elaborate on `open()`? I tried to do a simple replacing of the function with `open()`, but I got an encoding error.

Comment: I also expanded on my concerns with some edits above.

Comment: Why are you reluctant to use `venv`?

Comment: Okay, let me try using `venv` once, I tried using `penv` with conda once, but couldn't get anything to work.

Comment: One thing that might make you more comfortable with Python virtual environments is the [`pyenv` project](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv), which wraps `venv`. That, combined with [another, ancillary project by the same author](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv), is what I've come to rely upon for trying out various interpreters (not just versions of CPython) as well as combinations of libraries.

Answer (score 2):

The `file` constructor was already discouraged in Python 2.5 (maybe even earlier) in favor of the `open` function. In Python 3, it was removed entirely. So, it should just be a matter of:

```
f=open(filename, 'rb')
```

Note that, unlike your second version, I did not remove the `'rb'` "mode" argument. That `b` means "binary mode", and it's even more important in Python 3 than in Python 2. Without it, you're asking it to decode the file to Unicode text (using some default encoding), which isn't going to work with a binary file—it's going to give you something like the output in the second half of your question.

---

As a side note, you may want to rewrite the function like this:

```
def load_model(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        return pickle.load(f)
```

This guarantees that the file gets closed even if unpickling raises an exception.